# Grails DB Error at save ( not a domain or has no identifier.)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm developing a new application that needs to read existing db-tables in a legacy db. To do that I also have to have it work in the development environment too. But when I try to create a new record it fails with the following message:

```
URI
    /roleType/save
Class
    grails.web.mapping.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException
Message
    null
Caused by
    Cannot redirect for object [com.mytrading.legacy.RoleType : (unsaved)] it is not a domain or has no identifier. Use an explicit redirect instead
```

To get the controllers and views I ran "grails generate-all".

The domain, where I removed some fields for clarity, look like this:

```
class RoleType {
    int roleType

    static mapping = {
        table 'RoleType'
        version false
        id name: 'roleType', type:'int', generator:'assigned'
        roleType        column: 'RoleType'

    }
}
```

I don't know what they mean with: "is not a domain or has no identifier" and what they mean with explicit redirect, what shall I redirect to? Is that the only solution - I can't believe in that.

The Controller:

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SALES'])

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class RoleTypeController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond RoleType.list(params), model:[roleTypeCount: RoleType.count()]
    }

    def show(RoleType roleType) {
        respond roleType
    }

    def create() {
        respond new RoleType(params)
    }

    @Transactional
    def save(RoleType roleType) {
        if (roleType == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (roleType.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond roleType.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        roleType.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'roleType.label', default: 'RoleType'), roleType.id])
                redirect roleType
            }
            '*' { respond roleType, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }

    def edit(RoleType roleType) {
        respond roleType
    }

    @Transactional
    def update(RoleType roleType) {
        if (roleType == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (roleType.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond roleType.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        roleType.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'roleType.label', default: 'RoleType'), roleType.id])
                redirect roleType
            }
            '*'{ respond roleType, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    def delete(RoleType roleType) {

        if (roleType == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        roleType.delete flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'roleType.label', default: 'RoleType'), roleType.id])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'roleType.label', default: 'RoleType'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding code to the controller we get:

```
URI
    /roleType/save
Class
    java.lang.RuntimeException
Message
    null
Caused by
    org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors

Around line 30 of grails-app\controllers\com\torntrading\legacy\RoleTypeController.groovy

27:    @Transactional
28:    def save(RoleType roleType) {
29:    roleType.validate()
30:    throw new RuntimeException("${roleType.errors}")
31:        if (roleType == null) {
32:            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
33:            notFound()
```

Comment: So the problem is obviously in controller and you prefer to keep it's implementation in secret?

Comment: Sorry, but as I mentioned, the controller is created by scaffolding (generate-all) so it's not a secret but I can publish it too.

Comment: Ofcource it would be helpful to publish the problematic code.

Comment: Ok, the controller is your's

Comment: I added the code you sent and I got 0 errors. Look above.

Comment: The problem could also be in mappings. Do you really need to configure them explicitly? What if you try to remove the mappings closure at all, will it work then?

Comment: If I remove the mappings of ID it works, but I want it to work against the legacy database too, that's why I have to map the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your controller is using `id` which you replaced with `roleType`.

Comment: You are much wright, dynamo, I found out myself when I looked closer to the controller that addressed id as roleType.id. I didn't think of to look at the controller as it was generated by grails and I thought it would fix everything but apparently not. And thank's to you Anton as you put my eyes on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm not sure but it seems that the roleType has errors, but *roleType.hasErrors()* is invoked before *validate()* or *save()*.

I suppose that if you add some lines to the top:

```
def save(RoleType roleType) {
    roleType.validate()
    throw new RuntimeException("${roleType.errors}")

    if (roleType == null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You'll see the field and the failed constraint.

**UPDATED**

Looks strange. I would recommend to try explicit redirect as suggested or simplify the id-related mapping in your domain.